# pure code and impure code? I/O data type related

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
name <- getLine
```

The following paragraph is about how the line works. Can someone explain to me what this means? Thank you in advance.

> getLine is in a sense impure because its result value is not
>   guaranteed to be the same when performed twice. That's why it's sort
>   of tainted with the IO type constructor and we can only get that data
>   out in I/O code. And because I/O code is tainted too, any computation
>   that depends on tainted I/O data will have a tainted result.
>
> When I say tainted, I don't mean tainted in such a way that we can
>   never use the result contained in an I/O action ever again in pure
>   code. No, we temporarily un-taint the data inside an I/O action when
>   we bind it to a name. When we do name <- getLine, name is just a
>   normal string, because it represents what's inside the box.

Comment: This question is too broad. You might try another tutorial or haskell book that explains `IO` in a different way that makes more sense to you.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question @jberryman suggested is a nicer explanation than the one in terms of taints that you quoted. To it, we might also add that when you do `name <- getLine` and then use `name` elsewhere in the do-block you are specifying what *will* be done with the value obtained through `getLine`, whatever it turns out to be, once the recipe it specifies is executed.

Comment: I will be a bit more blunt than others. The paragraph you quoted is not a good way to think about `IO`. (How would you understand `[IO a]` or `IO a -> IO b` or `IO (IO a)` in this model?) You should find a different explanation of what the `IO` type constructor means.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph hints to the fact that you can't use `getLine` in a function which has a "pure" type, without the `IO` monad occurring in it. E.g. if we try to run

```
lineLength :: Int -> Int
lineLength n = n + length getLine
```

the compiler will complain because `length` expects a `String` (or any other list type) but `getLine` is an `IO String`. So there's a type mismatch.

But this does not mean that `length` and `getLine` can not be composed: here's how

```
lineLength :: Int -> IO Int
lineLength n = do
    line <- getLine
    return (n + length line)
```

Above we temporarily "remove the `IO`" since `line :: String`, so that `length` can be applied to it, and `n` added to the result. However, then we are forced to use `return` to transform a pure `Int` result into an `IO Int`.

Notice how the `IO` also ends up in the function signature: this is unavoidable.
In Haskell, if a function does impure things such as using `IO`, then the type system forces you to use `IO` in the type. This is the "taint" the quote is referring to: once you use an impure function/value with an `IO` type, then you have to use `IO` in the type of your own code, and any caller of that in turn will have to use `IO`. Impurity must be propagated in the type signatures.

This also means that if you see `f :: Int -> Int`, you can rely one the fact that the compiler proved the function to be pure: it will return the same result for the same input. (There are a few low-level ways to circumvent this, but they are not meant to be used in regular code.)